# How do i share my World instance across multiple step definition files in CucumberJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cucumber, protractor, cucumberjs

I am implementing a CucumberJS scenario which uses multiple steps across two different step definition files. The first step sets some variables on the World which have to be used by a step in the other step definition file.

The variable gets set correctly but when the step on the other file tries to read it it's undefined. Any ideas how to solve this apart from merging the step definition files?

example:

world.js

```
var World = function World() {
  this.client = '';
};

module.exports.World = World;
```

test.feature

```
Given a variable A
Then some other step
```

step1.steps.js

```
module.exports = function () {
    this.World = require(process.cwd() + '/test/features/support/world').World;

    this.Given(/^a Variable A$/, function () {
        this.client = 'abc';
    });
};
```

step2.steps.js

```
module.exports = function () {
    this.World = require(process.cwd() + '/test/features/support/world').World;

    this.Then(/^some other step$/, function () {
        console.log(this.client);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting `this.client` instead of `this.World.client`. Moreover you should use an object and not a constructor in `world.js`:

world.js

```
module.exports = {
    client: ''
};
```

step1.steps.js

```
var world = require('./test/features/support/world.js');

module.exports = function () {
    this.Given(/^a Variable A$/, function () {
        world.client = 'abc';
    });
};
```

step2.steps.js

```
var world = require('./test/features/support/world.js');

module.exports = function () {
    this.Then(/^some other step$/, function () {
        console.log(world.client);
    });
};
```

Comment: That indeed did the trick, although it differs from the official documentation. thank you!

Comment: @Florent B. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48297950/cucumberjs-how-to-use-worldconstructor-across-different-features

Comment: @Florent B. how to get same value for `Date.now()` across different features ?

Answer (score 0):

You could directly parameterise your test.feature :

```
Given a variable "abc"
Then some other step
```

now pass this variable in your step

step1.steps.js

```
module.exports = function() {
  this.World = require(process.cwd() + '/test/features/support/world').World;

  this.Given(/^a Variable "([^"]*)"$/, function(variable) {
    this.client = variable;
  });
};
```

step2.steps.js

```
module.exports = function() {
  this.World = require(process.cwd() + '/test/features/support/world').World;

  this.Then(/^some other step$/, function() {
    console.log(this.client); // would print abc
  });
};
```